# PHP - Submit form with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, forms, tags, textarea

I need to submit a form using PHP to send it to CouchBase and store it there with the HTML tags included (`<p>` tags and what not, just basic HTML). I am using CLEditor to create the HTML tags for people to input into a text field so that way when someone puts in bold text in a form it looks like this:

```
<span style="font-size: large;">Highlights of what your hotel has to offer.</span>
```

So I am getting started to send the information through the form using the action attribute, but how do I send that information through with the HTML tags included?

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

Figured I just do a cURL request and call the field. But what do I use to call to the information in that field to pull the raw html?

PHP:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url =  $_SESSION['extranetRequest'] . '?action=sendDesc&guid=' . $_SESSION['guid'] . '&username=' . $_SESSION['u_name'];
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $_POST[''] ); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            print curl_error($curl);
        } else {
            curl_close($curl);
        }
?>
```

UPDATE 2:

Okay, so I got a better idea of what I'm doing. I am using CLEditor to really allow people to edit their own text and what not to be submitted to be viewed somewhere else. But now I can't get the data from that to be posted like so:

HTML:

```
<form action="assets/php/sendHTML.php" name="hotelDescForm" id="hotelDesc" method="POST" class="hotelDesc">
                <div class="row push-down">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h1 style="font-size: 24px;"><span class="orange-title">hotel description</span></h1>
                            <textarea class="textarea" rows="8" style="width: 900px;" name="hotelDesc" class="hotelDesc" id="hotelDesc" value="">Text Is Here. Start working.</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <br>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-success btn-large"><i id="update-button" class="icon-refresh"></i> Update Information</button>
                    </form>
```

jQuery is just calling to the textarea to configure the textbox with CLEditor.

PHP:

```
    <?php 
session_start();
  $data['data'] = $_POST['demo'];
  $desc = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url =  $_SESSION['extranetRequest'] . '?action=sendDesc&desc='. var_dump($_POST) .'&guid=' . $_SESSION['guid'] . '&username=' . $_SESSION['u_name'];
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     var_dump($_POST) ); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            print curl_error($curl);
            echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
            echo "alert('Failed'); window.location.href='https://hotelmobidev.jvgames.com/profile';";
            echo "</script>\n";
        } else {
            curl_close($curl);
            echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
            echo "alert('Worked'); window.location.href='https://hotelmobidev.jvgames.com/profile';";
            echo "</script>\n";
        }
?>
```

What CLEditor does it is creates an iFrame, so I need a way to get around that and post the data put in the text box. Thanks guys!

Comment: There's no particular reason that submitting html markup is any different than any other content.  If you're filtering the submission at some point, that would remove the html markup - however, you didn't post any of the related code, so we can't say for sure.

Comment: I need it to send with the HTML markup that is the thing, there isn't much code to show. I'm wondering if I should basically cURL the data to get a full description to the database. I can't use a url request because the url would be enormous. I'm just looking for some help on sending the data (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I decided to show this incase anyone else has this problem with CKEditor. All I'm doing is sending out data to a server with the tags in place. Using a cURL statement in PHP.

PHP:

```
<?php 
session_start();
  $editor_data = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];
  $data['data'] = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url =  $_SESSION['extranetRequest'] . '?action=sendDesc&guid=' . $_SESSION['guid'] . '&username=' . $_SESSION['u_name'];
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            print curl_error($curl);
        } else {
            curl_close($curl);

        }

?>
```

And on the HTML side...

```
<form action="assets/php/sendHTML.php" name="hotelDescForm" id="hotelDesc" method="POST" class="hotelDesc">
                    <div class="row push-down">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <h1 style="font-size: 24px;"><span class="orange-title">hotel description</span></h1>
                                <textarea name="editor1" style="width: 900px;" rows="8"></textarea>
                                <script>
                                    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
                                        height: 300,
                                        width: 900
                                    });
                                </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <br>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-success btn-large"><i id="update-button" class="icon-refresh"></i> Update Information</button>
                        </form>
```

In case you guys have any questions on why this works let me know! Thanks again for everyone that helped!

Answer (score 0):

The CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS call is where you do it according to the PHP manual page. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
>
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files
>   can be sent using CURLFile.

You would take:

```
$field = '<span style="font-size: large;">Highlights of what your hotel has to offer.</span>';
```

And then in your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS would be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field);
```

Thing is you probably need to make sure that your HTML is escaped properly. For example & = & and like that.

Comment: What about if I am using something like CKEditor? How would I handle all of that data.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just used to using it with simple stuff like parameters.